# Public Folder Rule triggering for all e-mails recieved

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2013

We have a Team public folder which is set-up to receive e-mails from multiple Client specific address i.e it will pick up messages sent from 'client1@mycompany.com' and client3@mycompany.com

Using this a team inbox works fine but allows us to give out semi-unique/personalised e-mails to our clients to contact us on.

I have a rule set-up on this public folder to look for e-mails sent directly to a certain e-mail address and to send an auto-reply i.e if an e-mail comes in and the "to" address was 'client3@mycompany.com' it would send an auto-reply.

The problem is that it is sending out a reply to any message that comes in to the folder regardless of the e-mail address that it was sent to.
Does a public folder correctly see which e-mail was sent to or does the exchange server change the 'to' when dealing with incoming mail destined for a public folder?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I wonder how did you set up the rule? Like the link below?

https://www.wlv.ac.uk/its/self-help/university-email/email-for-staff/public-folders-auto-reply/

With my test in Exchange 2013 lab, I created a public folder and set auto-reply rule, when I clicked 'sent directly to' option, all incoming messages to the public folder received auto-reply mail. After canceling the option, only the recipients including 'user007' would receive auto reply mail. Please have a try.

[image]

Comment: I have set-up the rule as per the link. When I tried turn off the tick box for "Sent Directly To" it just stopped sending out auto-reply messages to anyone.

Comment: Have you added certain e-mail address 'client3@mycompany.com' in 'Sent To' option? i tested in my lab, after configuring rule like screenshot above for public folder, then i sent message to user007 and to/cc/bcc public folder, it returned auto-reply message.

Comment: How many e-mails address are used by that public folder in your test lab?